# android sqlitedatabasehelper database not found problem/error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, path, android-sqlite

So this is my database helper that I have used for quite a long time.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

    //The Androids default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"+MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME+"/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "fulldb";//name of your Database

    File DBFile = new File(DB_PATH, "fulldb");

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
      * Constructor
      * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
      * @param context
      */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
      * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
      * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();


        if(dbExist){

            //do nothing - database already exist

        } else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
            copyDataBase(DBFile);


            } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }


    }







    /**
      * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
      * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{

            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch(SQLiteException e){


        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }



    private void copyDataBase(File DBFile) throws IOException
    {
        AssetManager am = myContext.getAssets();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DBFile);
        DBFile.createNewFile();
        byte []b = new byte[1024];
        int i, r;
        String []Files = am.list("");
        Arrays.sort(Files);
        for(i=1;i<15;i++) //I have definitely less than 10 files; you might have more
        {
            String fn = String.format("0%d.db", i);
            if(Arrays.binarySearch(Files, fn) < 0) //No such file in assets - time to quit the loop
                break;
            InputStream is = am.open(fn);
            while((r = is.read(b)) != -1)
                os.write(b, 0, r);
            is.close();
        }
        os.close();
    }


    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

IT works fine on my emulator on version 27 of android. But On version 28 I get:

```
    2020-03-08 22:03:24.833 6843-6843/com.packagename E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 36667 of [0c55d17973]
2020-03-08 22:03:24.833 6843-6843/com.packagename E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:36667: (2) open(/data/data/com.packagename/databases/fulldb) - 
2020-03-08 22:03:24.838 6843-6843/com.packagename E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.packagename/databases/fulldb'.
```

and as a result of that i get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packagename/appname.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
```

My guess is that different android versions save the databases in different paths, and it seems like the path must be set more dynamically.

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"+MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME+"/databases/";
```

What are your guys guesses? DO you see any reason why on this particular version the database is not found? Can I make the database path dynamic in order to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: You could [use `getDatabasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?hl=en#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)), which has been around for a decade or so.

Comment: Can you please give it as an answer with code? I get confused with it and File() function

Comment: Well, personally, I would not be using the code from your question. I have railed against it since it appeared in 2009. If you are using Room, `RoomDatabase.Builder` now has `createFromAsset()` which handles this for you. Otherwise, I would be using [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). While that is no longer being maintained, in principle it should still work.

Comment: About the only time I use `getDatabasePath()` is in other utility code, such as [encrypting a SQLCipher for Android database](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v9.0/Database/SQLCipherPassphrase-AndroidStudio/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/constants/DatabaseHelper.java#L33-L58).

Comment: @CommonsWare why would you not be using it? I don't use room,  is there any one line of code that you can suggest me try to make it work?

Comment: Please? I can't seem to make it work no matter what I try